# Assign a role to the group using cloud resource manager api in gcp. I'm new to gcp, my understanding is of beginner level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

As the title states I'm assigning a role to a group  using cloud resource mananger api using python client library.
Here's the code :

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient import errors
 
service = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials= delegated_credentials)

def assign_custom_role_to_group(project_id, role_name, group_email):
    try:
        # Define the request body
        policy = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=project_id).execute()
        #print("GET IAM", policy['version'])
        bindings = policy.get('bindings', [])


        # Add the custom role to the bindings
        bindings.append({
            "role": role_name,
            "members": ["group:group_email"],
            "etag" : "BwXy6qC04wk=",
            "version" : 1
        })
        policy['bindings'] = bindings

        # Execute the request
        service.projects().setIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body=policy).execute()

        print(f'Successfully assigned custom role {role_name} to group {group_email}')
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

For this code I'm getting the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsnjm.png).
Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the value that you use for the projectID (even partly redacted) and the role? In addition remove the space in that part `'members':  ['group:' + group_email],`. Error 400 is a mal formatted request, something that your provide contains mistakes

Comment: Hi Guillaume,   project ID : gcp-{env}{project_num}-{nprd}-{last_4_digits_project_id} and the role : role/viewer.

Comment: I tried using resource manager api as well, here is the json body :                                                       
   {
  "role": "roles/editor",
  "members": [
    "group : group_name"
  ]
}.  For this data also I got the following error.

Comment: "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"role\": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"members\": Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [{
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"role\": Cannot find field."
          },
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"members\": Cannot find field."

Comment: You still have space in your group definition. remove the space, like that `group:group_name`

Comment: I Have removed the space but still the same error.

Comment: **service.projects().setIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body=policy).execute()**.  After I replaced the above line code worked fine. Thank you Guillaume for your concern and help.